# find command in python failing with "missing argument to -exec"

Tags: python, linux, command

I am trying to find files older than certain number of days and remove them

```
subprocess.call(['find', DIRECTORY, '-mtime', '+5', '-exec', 'rm', '{}', r'\ '])
```

Why is this call giving me `missing argument to -exec` error message

Comment: Be careful, your command will delete **directories** as well as files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using `exec`, you need a semicolon to indicate the end of the command.

```
subprocess.call(['find', DIRECTORY, '-mtime', '+5', '-exec', 'rm', '{}', ';'])
```

Comment: Or a `+` if you want to minimize the # of new processes.

Comment: @Drt When issuing the command in a shell you need to escape `;` to avoid the shell interpreting it as a command separator.  Since you aren't invoking a shell script, escaping is not required.